# SVN and Android with gradle

Tags: android, svn, gradle

I just need to commit my code to our SVN Server in our enterprise network with very limited access to internet.

My question is, if I am connected to our enterprise network I cannot sync my project because most of the libraries in gradle are blocked by our security team, is there a way to resolve this?

I just to annoying to switch between networks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting proxy server in proxy setting in android studio settings.

Comment: Yes, we have a proxy but that proxy is blocking most of the libraries I'm using in gradle and they use a script as proxy, not the traditional way.